# Make a mapkit annotation slide into its new location

Tags: objective-c, ios, mapkit

IOS 4 lets you modify the locations of mapkit annotations by setting their location property, however this simply jumps it into its new position.

On the other hand, the blue dot that signifies the users current location slides nicely into its new location whenever it is updated.

Is there anyway I can do these sorts of animations when I update the location of my annotations? I suppose I could divide the long/lat points between the 2 locations and update the location at certain incremeents to make it seem like its animating but I'm not sure if thats very efficient.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried beginning and animation block, updating the position and commiting the block? Not sure but worth a go.